# Doubts about regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this `"87987987 / 78979878978"` and which both numbers do not have any limit in length, and between it can be anything, in this example I showed a `"/"` but it can be a letter, a vowel or even a number but there's a space between them, which is a delimiter.

How can I create a regex to work it out?

Plus, the regex should also work in this scenario "789787987897" without a delimiter and a second number.

I tried something like this `"([\a-z]*?) (.) ([\a-z]*?) "` but didn't work out.

Comment: It would help if the regex you tried explicitly looked for digits... (`\d` or `[0-9]`)

Comment: `^[0-9]+.+[0-9]+$`

Comment: gonna be hard to make a regex that follows both rules: has a delimiter and not a delimiter.  How could one capture 123 / 567 AND 123567 and know to split the second?  Need more conditions.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko He says there's spaces for delimiters, so the regex should probably have spaces in.

Comment: What do you mean by "work it out"? What output are you hoping for in the two scenarios you describe?

Comment: Thanks,  Dmitry Bychenko, it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression should work:

```
^(\d+)\D*?(\d*)$
```

The idea is to match as many digits as possible with `\d+` at the beginning of the string `^`, then match as few non-digits as possible with `\D*?`, and finally match zero or more digits at the end of the string `$`.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/Vv1lk0/1)

Note parentheses around `\d+` and `\d*`: they are setting up *regex capturing groups*. You can use these groups to harvest the numbers matched by regex from your C# code.

**Note:** If you would like to allow digits in the "space in between", use `.*` in place of `\D*`.

Comment: What about (98)7987987 \ (21)9879879 ?

I tried to modify this regex that you wrote, but it doesn't work when there's only the first part

Comment: @joab What should the expression capture in that case? (a) `7987987` and `9879879`, or (b) `(98)7987987` and `(21)9879879`? If it's "b", the regex would get a lot more difficult. Should it reject `21)9879879` and `(21(9879879`?

Comment: Both.

Cuz here in my database there are like this "7987987 ... 9879879" and "     
 "(98)7987987 .... (21)9879879"

Comment: Actually, I asked as if the first part and second were numbers, but the truth is they can have some other characters such as: "/ - ()"

Comment: @joab If you need to allow other characters without regard to their order, say, parentheses, you could use `[()\d]` in place of `\d`. This would match strings like `(((8798)(8839`, though. If you need to add dash `-` and `^` to the list of allowed characters, put them all the way at the back, i.e. `[()\d^-]`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using *achors* in order to get the very *first* and *last* numbers:

```
  string pattern = @"^(?<first>[0-9]+)(\s+.*\s+(?<last>[0-9]+))?$";
```

Tests

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "8798798778979878978", // one number 
    "123 456 789",         // number 456 is a delimiter 
    "123 / 456",           // delimiter is / 
    "123 /456",            // failed delimeter / (no space after /), no match
    "abc"                  // no match
  };

  var report = tests
    .Select(line => new {
      line = line,
      match = Regex.Match(line, pattern)
    })
    .Select(item => item.match.Success
       ? $"{item.line,-30} first: {item.match.Groups["first"].Value,-20} last: {item.match.Groups["last"].Value,-20}"
       : $"{item.line,-30} NO MATCH");

   Console.WriteLines(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, report));
```

Outcome:

```
8798798778979878978            first: 8798798778979878978  last:                     
123 456 789                    first: 123                  last: 789                 
123 / 456                      first: 123                  last: 456                 
123 /456                       NO MATCH
abc                            NO MATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        var s = "1204852384 / 1245983245";

        var p = s.Split(" ".ToCharArray())
        .Select(num => { if (long.TryParse(num, out var number)) return (long?)number; return null; })
        .Where( num => num.HasValue)
        .Select(num => num.Value)
        .ToList();

        long first = long.MinValue;
        long last = long.MinValue;

        if (p.Count >= 2)
            last = p.Last ();

        if (p.Count > 0)
            first = p.First ();

        Console.WriteLine (first);
        Console.WriteLine (last);

        Console.ReadLine ();
    }
}
```

Comment: and as a second afterthought: presented with "hello 1234674 Nil 21487 arca" you still get 1234674 as 'first' and '21487' as 'last' values although you have quite a lot of other garbage in your Input.
And your "numbers have no Limit in length" requirement kills this solution. Should have read more carefully.